# What is the quickest way to subtract a variable from a number and set the variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, math, subtraction

Is there a quicker way to do `x = 128 - x`?

Comment: `x -= 128;` is it?

Comment: @Jai Nope, I'm trying to shorten `x = 128 - x`

Comment: So i guess that is the only way to subtract it.

Comment: @Jai Yes. `x` is always smaller than (or equal to) `128`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No

If it was a division or multiplication by powers of 2, you could use bitwise shift operators to make it faster, but in this case, nothing is better than `x = 128 - x`